# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Olá!

No meu código JavaScript recebo o seguinte erro: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined". Como sou nova na área, não entendo muito bem como resolver o problema, alguém pode me ajudar a identifica-lo?

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
var marks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
    marks[i] = createMark(i); /*ERRO*/
}

function createMark() {
    var imagePath = "marker" + (i + 1) + ".png";
    var image = imagePath;
    var markers = [];
    var lat = locations[i].split(',')[0]; /*ERRO*/
    var long = locations[i].split(',')[1];
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
    marker.setTitle("Cliente");
    var textOrder = "<strong> Ponto: </strong> " + (i + 1) + ". <br> <strong> Latitude: </strong>" + lat + ", <strong> Longitude: </strong>" + long;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: textOrder
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: Esqueceste de dar argumentos à função `function createMark()`... acho que queres `function createMark(i)`. Mas há mais coisas, essa função não retorna nada, por isso `marks[i]` vai dar `undefined`.

Comment: Agradeço Sérgio pela ajuda! Mas anteriormente este código funcionou, só agora começou a me retornar erros... Se não for abuso de minha parte, saberia me dizer que tipos de argumentos devo passar para marks[i]?

Comment: No final da função junta `return marker;` Assim a intância do marcador fica guardada, no respetivo `mark[i]`.

Comment: Sérgio, mais uma vez obrigada! Ainda sim não funcionou... Vou postar o código completo...

Comment: Podes fazer um exemplo a funcionar? (que mostre o erro e que tenha HTML). Acho que vais precisar de estas 3 alterações: https://paste.ofcode.org/33TFGAbVx5D5EjsVapDMgqd

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Sérgio!!! Obrigada!!! :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 coisas a corrigir:

```
function createMark(i) { // <--------------- mudança 1
    var imagePath = "marker" + (i + 1) + ".png";
    var image = imagePath;
    var markers = [];
    if (!locations[i]) return null; // <--------------- mudança 2
    var lat = locations[i].split(',')[0]; /*ERRO*/
    var long = locations[i].split(',')[1];
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
    marker.setTitle("Cliente");
    var textOrder = "<strong> Ponto: </strong> " + (i + 1) + ". <br> <strong> Latitude: </strong>" + lat + ", <strong> Longitude: </strong>" + long;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: textOrder
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker; // <--------------- mudança 3
}
```

A primeira é falta do `i` dentro do escopo da função.
A segunda é uma salvaguarda caso `locations[i]` não tenha o que é esperado.
A terceira é para a função retornar algo para ser guardado em `marks[i]`

Comment: estou com mais uma dúvida sobre o assunto, poderia me ajudar? Se puder me chamar em chat, agradeceria muito. Obrigada!!!!

Comment: @Z.. podes escrever aqui. Quando tiveres mais pontos podes escrever no chat também

Comment: Ok @Sergio!! A dúvida está em resposta a essa questão...

Answer (score 2):

Na linha onde está ocorrendo o erro você passa o a variável i como parametro para a function createMark(), mas acontece que essa function não está esperando nenhum parâmetro:

```
for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
    marks[i] = createMark(i); /*ERRO*/
}
```

O que deve ser feito é alterar a linha

```
function createMark() {
```

Para

```
function createMark(i) {
```

Comment: Funcionou!! Obrigada!!!