# Google Maps API JavaScript com Geocoding Service

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Estou usando agora outras utilidades da Google Maps API JavaScript, alterei algumas partes do código e ele voltou a ter problemas mais ou menos nesta mesma parte em que o @Sergio me ajudou Link da pergunta: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189907/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-split-of-undefined/191316?noredirect=1#comment395031_191316) , segue o código JS:

JS:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); // linha igual ao necessário
var marks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
    marks[i] = createMark(i); /*ERRO*/
}

function createMark(i) { 
    var imagePath = "marker" + (i + 1) + ".png";
    var image = imagePath;
    var markers = [];
    if (!locations[i]) return null;
    //inserindo nova parte da API
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': location}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[i].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[i].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    }); //função inserida
    marker.setTitle("Cliente"); /*ERRO*/
    var textOrder = "<strong> Ponto: </strong> " + (i + 1);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: textOrder
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map); //linha inserida
    });
    return marker; 
} }
```

ERRO RETORNADO:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined
     at createMark (map_clients.js:67)
     at mapCreate (map_clients.js:45)
```

Vlw ai pessoal!

Comment: dentro da sua function createMark(i) você está setando marker.setTitle('Cliente'), mas você não iniciou a variavel marker... Você deve colocar var marker = new google.maps.Marker(...) que está dentro do if fora do escopo do if ou colocar o marker.setTitle para dentro do if

Comment: @Hugo funcionou, obrigada! Desculpe a impertinência, mas sou nova com isso e não sei muito bem lidar com alguns erros... Após fazer o que você disse, ele arrumou aqueles erros, porém retornou este "InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object"

Comment: Por nada, estamos aqui para ajudar... Sobre o seu outro erro, você terá que criar outra pergunta e coloca também o local onde você está tentando este "setPosition", aparentemente você está tentando fazer um setPosition com um objeto diferente de: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)

Comment: Ok @Hugo! Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Se a resposta do hugo resolveu este problema deves dar a resposta como aceite, para ficar mais facil para outros utilizadores que tenham o mesmo problema. Bem vinda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa iniciar a variavel `marker` , você está iniciando em um scopo e tentando 'resgatar' ela fora do scopo.
Mude a linha da onde você chama `marker.setTitle("Cliente"); /*ERRO*/` para abaixo de

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[i].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });
```

Segue codigo alterado(Obs: alterei apenas o lugar da linha: `marker.setTitle("Cliente"); /*ERRO*/` ):

```js
function createMark(i) { 
    var imagePath = "marker" + (i + 1) + ".png";
    var image = imagePath;
    var markers = [];
    if (!locations[i]) return null;
    //inserindo nova parte da API
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': location}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[i].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[i].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });
            marker.setTitle("Cliente"); /*ERRO*/
            var textOrder = "<strong> Ponto: </strong> " + (i + 1);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: textOrder
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
               geocodeAddress(geocoder, map); //linha inserida
            });
           return marker; 
           } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    }); //função inserida
}
```

Comment: Funcionando!!! Obrigada!